# Is there a way to add an already created parser as a subparser in argparse?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

Normally, to add a subparser in `argparse` you have to do:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparser()
subparser = subparsers.add_parser()
```

The problem I'm having is I'm trying to add another command line script, with its own parser, as a subcommand of my main script. Is there an easy way to do this?

---

EDIT: To clarify, I have a file `script.py` that looks something like this:

```
def initparser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--foo')
    parser.add_argument('--bar')
    return parser

def func(args):
    #args is a Namespace, this function does stuff with it

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initparser().parse_args()
```

So I can run this like:

```
python script.py --foo --bar
```

I'm trying to write a module `app.py` that's a command line interface with several subcommands, so i can run something like:

```
python app.py script --foo --bar
```

Rather than copy and pasting all of the `initparser()` logic over to `app.py`, I'd like to be able to directly use the parser i create from initparser() as a sub-parser. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12):

You could use the `parents` parameter

```
p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
s=p.add_subparsers()
ss=s.add_parser('script',parents=[initparser()],add_help=False)
p.parse_args('script --foo sst'.split())
```

`ss` is a parser that shares all the arguments defined for `initparser`.  The `add_help=False` is needed on either `ss` or `initparser` so `-h` is not defined twice.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [shlex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) module as it sounds to me like you're trying to hack the `ArgumentParser` to do something that it wasn't actually intended to do.

Having said that, it's a little difficult to figure out a good answer without examples of what it is, exactly, that you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be addressed by a declarative wrapper for argparse. The one I wrote is called [Argh](http://argh.rtfd.org). It helps with separating definition of commands (with all arguments-related stuff) from assembling (including subparsers) and dispatching.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way old question, but I wanted to throw out another alternative. And that is to think in terms of inversion of control. By this I mean the root `ArgumentParser` would manage the creation of the subparsers:

```
# root_argparser.py
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Namespace

__ARG_PARSER = ArgumentParser('My Script')
__SUBPARSERS = __ARG_PARSER.add_subparsers(dest='subcommand')
__SUBPARSERS.required = True


def get_subparser(name: str, **kwargs) -> ArgumentParser:
    return __SUBPARSERS.add_parser(name, **kwargs)


def parse_args(**kwargs) -> Namespace:
    return __ARG_PARSER.parse_args(**kwargs)
```

---

```
# my_script.py
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from root_argparse import get_subparser

__ARG_PARSER = get_subparser('script')
__ARG_PARSER.add_argument('--foo')
__ARG_PARSER.add_argument('--bar')

def do_stuff(...):
    ...
```

---

```
# main.py
from root_argparse import parse_args
import my_script

if __name__ == '__main__':
   args = parse_args()
   # do stuff with args
```

Seems to work okay from some quick testing I did.